# PixelExperience build.ninja failed when trying to make build target

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an android image using the PixelExperience, and I keep on running into the following error no matter the build target using lunch.

Full Code

`source build/envsetup.sh` ✓

`lunch aosp_tissot-userdebug` ✓

`m -j4` ✖ <- Error on output here

Output

```
11:32:57 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
[100% 47/47] /Volumes/PE/source_code/out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build /Volumes/PE/source_code/out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: /Volumes/PE/source_code/out/soong/build.ninja
/Volumes/PE/source_code/out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l /Volumes/PE/source_code/out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b /Volumes/PE/source_code/out/soong -n /Volumes/PE/source_code/out -d /Volumes/PE/source_code/out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile /Volumes/PE/source_code/out/soong/.bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o /Volumes/PE/source_code/out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
internal error: failed to find dex jar path for module "WfdCommon"
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

#### failed to build some targets (01:57 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I'm running on macOS Big Sur version 11.0.1

Answer (score -3):

go device tree device.mk

//delete this code

PRODUCT_BOOT_JARS += 
WfdCommon

Comment: Hi There. How does this solve OPs problem. Consider adding some explanation if possbile.